# как по клику добавить autoplay для тега video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, видео

Есть блок с тегом видео, в котором через скрипт меняется `src`.

```js
$('#btn_1').on('click', function() {
  $('#MainFrame')[0].src = 'video1.mp4';
});

$('#btn_2').on('click', function() {
  $('#MainFrame')[0].src = 'video2.mp4';
});

$('#btn_3').on('click', function() {
  $('#MainFrame')[0].src = 'video3.mp4';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="videoWRP" class="video-container">
  <video id="MainFrame" src="video.mp4" preload controls playsinline autobuffer></video>
  <br>
  <button class='play'>Play/pause</button>

  <div class="btnWRP">
    <button id="btn_1" class="btn">Сценарий 1</button>
    <button id="btn_2" class="btn">Сценарий 2</button>
    <button id="btn_3" class="btn">Сценарий 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос, как по клику добавить `autoplay` для тега `video`?

Comment: По какому клику должен навешиваться автоплей? Когда-то должен сниматься?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, для начала просто пропишите в каждой функции для кнопок что-то типа

```
$('#MainFrame')[0].play();
```

Чтобы получилось вроде

```js
$('#btn_1').on('click', function() {
    $('#MainFrame')[0].src= 'video1.mp4';
    $('#MainFrame')[0].play();
});

$('#btn_2').on('click', function() {
    $('#MainFrame')[0].src= 'video2.mp4';
    $('#MainFrame')[0].play();
});

$('#btn_3').on('click', function() {
    $('#MainFrame')[0].src= 'video3.mp4';
    $('#MainFrame')[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="videoWRP" class="video-container">
  <video id="MainFrame" src="video.mp4" preload controls playsinline autobuffer></video>
  <br>
  <button class='play'>Play/pause</button>

  <div class="btnWRP">
    <button id="btn_1" class="btn">Сценарий 1</button>
    <button id="btn_2" class="btn">Сценарий 2</button>
    <button id="btn_3" class="btn">Сценарий 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но, Вам надо будет доработать кнопку "Play/Pause".
Дальше гуглите "работа с аудио и видеопотоками JavaScript"

Comment: Пробовал нечто подобное, но коряво - не заработало, поэтому заморочился с autoplay.
Ваш вариант хороший.

Answer (score 1):

Так после выбора сценария будет навешиваться атрибут `autoplay` на видео, не могу правда понять какая польза в такой задаче.

```js
$('#btn_1').on('click', function() {
  $('#MainFrame')[0].src = 'video1.mp4';
});

$('#btn_2').on('click', function() {
  $('#MainFrame')[0].src = 'video2.mp4';
});

$('#btn_3').on('click', function() {
  $('#MainFrame')[0].src = 'video3.mp4';
});
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#MainFrame').prop('autoplay', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="videoWRP" class="video-container">
  <video id="MainFrame" src="video.mp4" preload controls playsinline autobuffer></video>
  <br>
  <button class='play'>Play/pause</button>

  <div class="btnWRP">
    <button id="btn_1" class="btn">Сценарий 1</button>
    <button id="btn_2" class="btn">Сценарий 2</button>
    <button id="btn_3" class="btn">Сценарий 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```